# Putting a PHP function into a button

Tags: php

How can I put this function into a button? It needs to show when I click the button.

```
public function index()
    {
        $student_applied_tbl = $this->create_table([
            //tbl_id 
            "tbl_id"        => "tbl_student_applied",
            //column headers name address type and button headers
            "tbl_headers"   => ["Student_Name","Service Name","Status",""],
            "tbl_rows"      => []   
        ], true, base_url("index.php/dashboard/get_applied"));
```

Comment: PHP is a server side language, you can't put a function on a button, but you can make the button take you to a page where PHP will be executed

Comment: in button side type `onclick="dosomecall();"` in you dosomecall use ajax post with some `data` values, if `isset[$_POST['data']]` call the php function.

Answer (score 0):

"Put the function into a button"? You mean execute the function when you click the button?

Here is how to achieve that using **PHP, JavaScript/jQuery, AJAX**:

```
<input type="submit" name="run-function-button" id="run-function-button" value="Execute Function">

<script>
$('#run-function-button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "your-file.php",
        data: {
            name: "run-function"
        }
    });
});
</script>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    index();
}
?>
```

Or you can use **PHP with `<form>`**:

```
<form action="your-file.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="run-function-button" id="run-function-button" value="Execute Function">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    index();
}
?>
```